# Tricky sorting of quarter values to a specific order while grouping in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where I would like to rearrange and sort quarter values in numerical order, grouping by the 'id' column

**Data**

```
    id  date    stat
    aa  q1 22   y
    aa  q1 23   y
    aa  q2 22   y
    aa  q2 23   y
    aa  q3 22   y
    aa  q3 23   y
    aa  q4 22   y
    aa  q4 23   ok
    bb  q1 22   n
    bb  q1 23   n
    bb  q2 22   n
    bb  q2 23   n
    bb  q3 22   n
    bb  q3 23   n
    bb  q4 22   n
    bb  q4 23   ok
```

**Desired**

```
 id date    stat
aa  q1 22   y
aa  q2 22   y
aa  q3 22   y
aa  q4 22   y
aa  q1 23   y
aa  q2 23   y
aa  q3 23   ok
aa  q4 23   n
bb  q1 22   n
bb  q2 22   n
bb  q3 22   n
bb  q4 22   n
bb  q1 23   n
bb  q2 23   n
bb  q3 23   n
bb  q4 23   ok
```

**Doing**

Since my data is in quarters, I am using this

```
import pandas as pd    
pd.to_datetime(date).sort_values().to_period('Q')
```

However, I also need to group these by the 'id' column as the desired output shows.
Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: sorted_data = data.sort_values(by=['id','date'], inplace=True)

Comment: Hi @Alex this one didn't work - will troubleshoot this, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename axis, split q to extract integer, sort by

```
df[['temp1','temp2']]=df['date'].str.split('\s', expand=True)
df=df.sort_values(by=['id','temp2']).drop(columns=['temp1', 'temp2'])

    id   date stat
0   aa  q1 22    y
1   aa  q2 22    y
2   aa  q3 22    y
3   aa  q4 22    y
4   aa  q1 23    y
5   aa  q2 23    y
6   aa  q3 23   ok
7   aa  q4 23    n
8   bb  q1 22    n
9   bb  q2 22    n
10  bb  q3 22    n
11  bb  q4 22    n
12  bb  q1 23    n
13  bb  q2 23    n
14  bb  q3 23    n
15  bb  q4 23   ok
```

Comment: Hi thank you @wwnde it is saying ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer - I am using the same values within my post - is there some conversion that needs to occur?

Comment: Thank you @wwnde, I do not see a change with this

Comment: See my edits Lynn

Comment: wow @wwnde this was a tricky one- I will see how you did - thank you kindly

Comment: was wondering @wwnde - my  full dataset has about 20 columns- it says ValueError: Columns must be same length as key - when I place the code in-  how do I adjust the code to fit the columns? or any insight? -  maybe  I need to add the appropriate temp columns I think

Comment: What are the temp columns doing? @wwnde are these placeholders?

Comment: The columns as generated cannot affect existing columns. Unless you have columns with the same names.

Comment: The temp columns are place holders.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.sort_values(by=['id', 'date'], inplace=True)
df.index = df['date']
df.index.to_period("Q")
```

Explanation:

`df.sort_values(by=['id', 'date'], inplace=True)` will first sort your data on the `id` column and then it'll sort that sorted data(i.e., on `id` column) on `date` column.

Comment: Hi thank you @mrverma this didnt work- no change occurred

Comment: It says ParserError: Unknown string format: q1 22 - although we are converting to datetime, however I think it has to do with how the quarters are displayed

Comment: i think the problem might be in data as the solution to this question mentions here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34505579/pandas-to-datetime-valueerror-unknown-string-format).
You may want to manually do the formatting of datetime using strftime from datetime module by passing it your date strings (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

Comment: also, as you mentioned in the reply to @wwnde 's answer to this problem that you're getting ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer, you may have some NaN values in your date column which you might want to deal with before using to_period('q')

Comment: ok thank you  I do not have any NaN in the datsaet though, it looks exactly like post